# Soapui script assertion how can it be iterated based on condition

Tags: soapui

In soapui my test step has 3 script assertion. i want soapui to execute the 2nd or 3rd script assertion if my 1st script assertion fails. how can i write a condition for the same in my groovy script or the script assertion.

Comment: Creating a conditional assertion based on the result of another assertion is awkward. Perhaps you should reconsider your approach. Can you give us an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the code,, as i have acheived what you told.. but if you can share the code @nikita it would be great